Is my approach of calculating adjusted standardized incidence ratios(SIR) correct?
I am trying to calculate the Standardized Incidence Ratio (SIR) to determine the effect of smoking on cancer using the following simulated data frame. The SIR and its 95% confidence interval (CI) for smoking on cancer need to be adjusted for sex and age groups.
Q: Is my approach correct?
library(dplyr)
    
set.seed(123)
n <- 1000
# Generate data
df <- data.frame(
  cancer_case = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),  # cancer
  smoking = sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  age_group = factor(sample(c("50-59", "60-69", "70-79"), n, 
                     replace = TRUE)),
  sex = factor(sample(c("male", "female"), n, replace = TRUE)),
  start_follow = sample(1990:2005, n, replace = TRUE),
  stop_follow = sample(1996:2015, n, replace = TRUE)
)

# Ensure that stop_follow is after start_follow
df <- df %>%
  mutate(stop_follow = pmax(start_follow + sample(1:10, n, 
                             replace = TRUE), stop_follow))

# Calculate person-years (pyrs).
# SIR = Observed / Expected

df <- df %>%
  mutate(pyrs = stop_follow - start_follow)
    
## Step 1: Count observed cases for both smokers and non-smokers
    
observed_cases <- df %>%
      group_by(smoking, age_group, sex) %>%
      summarise(observed = sum(cancer_case), .groups = 'drop')
    
## Step 2: Calculate person-years
    
person_years <- df %>%
      group_by(smoking, age_group, sex) %>%
      summarise(total_pyrs = sum(pyrs, na.rm = TRUE), 
                 .groups = 'drop')
    
## Step 3: Calculate incidence rates for the reference population (non-smokers)
    
reference_rates <- df %>%
      filter(smoking == 0) %>%
      group_by(age_group, sex) %>%
      summarise(rate = sum(cancer_case) / sum(pyrs), 
                 .groups = 'drop')
    
## Step 4: Calculate expected cases (if there were no smoking)
    Multiply the total person-years by the incidence rate of each group.
    
expected_cases <- person_years %>%
      left_join(reference_rates, by = c("age_group", "sex")) %>%
      mutate(expected = total_pyrs * rate)
    
## Step 5: Combine observed and expected cases
    
combined <- observed_cases %>%
  left_join(expected_cases, by = c("smoking", "age_group", "sex")) %>%
  group_by(smoking) %>%
  summarise(
    obs_cases = sum(observed, na.rm = TRUE),
    exp_cases = sum(expected, na.rm = TRUE),
    total_pyrs = sum(total_pyrs, na.rm = TRUE)
  )

## Step 6: Calculate SIR by dividing observed cases by expected cases
    
combined <- combined %>%
  
mutate(
    SIR = obs_cases / exp_cases,
    SE_log_SIR = sqrt(1 / obs_cases),
    lower = exp(log(SIR) - 1.96 * SE_log_SIR),
    upper = exp(log(SIR) + 1.96 * SE_log_SIR)
  )
    
## Step 7: Adjust the reference population values  
## Since non-smokers are my reference population, I changed the SE, 
## lower, and upper values to "ref".  

combined <- combined %>%
      mutate(
        SIR = ifelse(smoking == 0, 1.0, SIR),
        SE_log_SIR = ifelse(smoking == 0, "ref", SE_log_SIR),
        lower = ifelse(smoking == 0, "ref", lower),
        upper = ifelse(smoking == 0, "ref", upper)
      )

I am trying to implement what I read from my lecture materials and some sas codes. However, I am not good at SAS and I have difficulties translating them to R and getting similar results.
So I can't be sure whether my approach is correct. Some people use the overall incidence rate of the reference population instead of the incidence rate of the reference population for each grouping variable combinations. Using the overall incidence rate doesn't make any sense to me. Could you please let me know if this approach to calculating the SIR is correct, especially regarding the adjustment for sex and age groups? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Please be polite I came here to learn not to be insulted and I hope my question would also help others to learn.

The default for R is to use the "base group" defined by the factor used for grouping. If there is a sensible reference group, such as those cases unexposed to the feature of interest as a potential cause of association with mortality, then I agree that using that group makes more sense. If there is no unexposed group or the risk is being indexed by some category such as income that has no natural base level, then using the mean in the population might make more sense.
